# How can this code to compare version information be improved?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, versioninfo

I have a problem with my logic to compare version information.

Take this method:

```
bool CPTSDatabase::IsInstalledPublicTalksVersionSupported()
{
    CSettingsStore store(TRUE, TRUE);
    CString strPath, strVersion;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO* pVerInfo = nullptr;
    bool bOK = false;

    if (store.Open(_T("Software\\Community Talks\\Public Talks")))
    {
        if (store.Read(_T("AppPath"), strPath))
        {
            //yes, but is the path still valid
            if (PathFileExists(strPath))
            {
                pVerInfo = theApp.ExtractVersionInformation(strPath, strVersion);
                if (pVerInfo != nullptr)
                {
                    if (HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS) >= 20 &&
                        LOWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS) >= 0 &&
                        HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionLS) >= 3)
                    {
                        bOK = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bOK;
}
```

The issue is this bit:

```
if (HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS) >= 20 &&
    LOWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS) >= 0 &&
    HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionLS) >= 3)
{
    bOK = true;
}
```

The executable in question is now `21.0.1` and ofcourse the `pVerInfo->dwFileVersionLS` test is failing. Is there a more robust wat to check that the version in question is greater than `20.0.3` without a lot of `if` clauses?

Comment: Convert the version information into a 64-bit (or 128-bit) value, encoding the version into the respective 16- (or 32-) bit wide ranges. With that you can compare against a single value, e.g. `0x0014'0000'0003'0000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a 64bit int.

```
auto Version = [](WORD a, WORD b, WORD c)
{
  return int64_t(a)<<32 | int64_t(b)<<16 | int64_t(c);
};

if (Version(HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS),LOWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionMS),HIWORD(pVerInfo->dwFileVersionLS))>=Version(20,0,3))
{
  bOK = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Trying now. I had to add `HIWORD(...)` around the first value and the closing `)` for the second in the function call. Now testing.

Comment: Ironically code inspection is telling me that the variable `Version` does not change after construction and that it should be marked as a `const`. It seems like VC doesn't even realise it iis a function.

Comment: Rename it... ;)

Comment: What do you mean to rename it? Add the const?

Comment: auto Version -> auto VersionFromWORDToInt64

Comment: Thanks! And now it says not to use C style cats (eg: `int64_4(a)` etc. Other error has now gone.

Comment: I’ll try static_cast.

Comment: Confirmed - `static_cast<int64_t>(a) << 32 | static_cast<int64_t>(b) << 16 | static_cast<int64_t>(c);`. No more code inspection warnings now. :)

Comment: Just to mention that renaming the function from Version had no effect. It is all working so I am not worried. But I have sent feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-inspection-query-things-a-function-is-a-varia/1494787?from=email

Comment: Visual Studio is correct. `Version` is a variable that stores a lambda expression. The fact that you can invoke a lambda expression using function call syntax doesn't make it a function. The suggestion to make the variable `const` is reasonable, i.e. `auto const Version = ...`.